# $15$ men and $15$ women into $15$ couples

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Find the number of ways of dividing $15$ men and $15$ women into $15$ couples.

*My solution* is: First Man can be paired with any one of $15$ women in $15$ ways. Second Man can be paired in $14$ ways and so on. Hence total ways is $15!$

But *book solution* is like this:

Select one man from $15$ men and select one women from $15$ women which can be done in $\binom{15}{1}^2$. Similarly from $14$ men select one man and from $14$ women select one women which can be done in $\binom{14}{1}^2$. Hence to total number of ways is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{15} \binom{k}{1}^2=1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+15^2=\frac{15 \times 16 \times 31}{6}=1240$$

Comment: You are correct and the book is wrong. See the new/edited answers.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, can i know how should we frame the question to make book solution correct?

Comment: Adding instead of multiplying is something that I see rarely in counting. Addition $+$ corresponds to "or" while multiplication $\cdot$ to and.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test the solutions we can start with something simpler: $2$ men and $2$ women in $2$ couples. Direct counting gives that there are $2$ possible solutions (or couples). But the book's solution gives $$\sum_{k=1}^2 \dbinom{k}{1}^2=1^2+2^2=5$$ which is obviously wrong. Contrary your solution gives $2!=2$ which is correct.

Proceeding with $n=3$ confirms that your way of thinking is correct in contrast to the proposed solution which is not correct.

Comment: I don't see why these solutions are counted differently. In fact, the answer proposed by Umesh suggest that when describing "a way to organize 15 couples" you have to put in order $M_1,\ldots,M_n$. My question is basically this: according to the problem, what is a solution? For me, a solution looks like a SET $X=\{(m,n)\}$ where $\pi_1(X)=\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ and $\pi_2(X)=\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$, and each number from 1 to 15 appears only once as a first coordinate, and only once as a second coordinate. Am I correct?

Comment: As I emphasized before, they are the same SET and therefore they correspond to the same answer. Notice that the OP is not counting between the men who is going to be first, who is going to be second, and so on. (S)he only says to pick a fixed enumeration of the men, and start assigning to each men a partner. Thus, neither me nor the OP is counting both solutions $X=\{(1,1),(2,2),\ldots\}$ and $X=\{(2,2),(1,1)\}$ as different.

Comment: @Wore Hey, I think the opposite is true. The kid is correct and the book is wrong.

Comment: You reached the conclusion just as I was finishing typing my answer !

Comment: @trueblueanil I already upvoted your answer. I hurried into a wrong answer which confused the OP. Your credit

Comment: Thanks. I hope OP hasn't already rushed with the book answer to the exam hall !

Comment: @trueblueanil That will be largely my fault. I also hope to hear from him... but he seems to be gone!!

Comment: @JimmyR. I thought OP argument was ok, but I just wanted to make sure I was not having mistakes counting (which I often have)

Comment: @Wore It seems that I (often) count wrong too. And unfortunately it seems that the OP went to his exams with the wrong answer....

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with the book answer. There is no multiple counting in your solution.

Take a simple example $A,B,C$ and $a,b,c$

$Aa-Bb-Cc,\;\; Aa-Bc-Cb$
$Ab-Bc-Ca,\;\; Ab-Ba-Cc$
$Ac-Ba-Cb,\;\; Ac-Bb-Ca$

are clearly $3!=6$ ways of grouping the $3$ couples

The book would in fact give **more** groups here, $3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 14$

Can any one show me how you would get $14$ couples here !

The way OP has computed is a standard way of working out such a problem.

Comment: ok thanks my doubt is clarified now

Comment: You're welcome !